# How to make an Arduino file into an executable .exe

Tags: arduino, tcl, executable

I have an arduino file, which has a .ino extension. Is there a way to make this into an executable file with .exe extension? I want to be able to call it to execute from a TCL program.

EDIT:: Or, how would one run an Arduino .ino file from a TCL program?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be misunderstanding what the Arduino is about. The code in your .ino file gets uploaded to and executed on the Arduino microcontroller. The code does not run (execute) on the computer where you write your code.

If you want to communicate with the Arduino from your PC, you would typically do it through a serial or wifi connection. Do some searches on that (if that is what you are trying to do). There is a great deal of information and tutorials on that.

Comment: I want the Arduino to be able to communicate with a device other than the PC. That device uses TCL scripts

Comment: But I think I'll try executing the TCL file from the Arduino file; that seems like it will be more logical.

Comment: The more information you post, the better chance you have for getting some help. As it stands, you have not provided sufficient information. Edit your question with the specifics of your project (the "device" etc.)

Comment: FWIW, if you're using a serial connection, Tcl can most certainly be controlling it on the PC side. Probably can do it with a wifi connection too, but the details could get complex there…

Comment: @DonalFellows - he or she is talking about some "device" that is apparently not a PC. Who knows.